# Ubuntu Mate as Only OS on Mac

Tags: mac, mate

So I have this imac that my cousin gave me along with 4 servers. I want to find a way to put Ubuntu Mate on the imac not in dual boot but as the only OS on the computer. I have seen videos on Youtube of the same type of imac getting Ubuntu to boot but I have had no luck with any version of Ubuntu or Mate. I wonder if the guy isn't just full of it some how. I'm not worried about messing up the imac I can trash it if things go south but as is nothing is compatible with its old OS which is not update-able. I honestly thought Linux could be installed on pretty much anything.

I have tried holding "Command" while booting to open up the boot menu which shows all versions of Ubuntu DVD disks as "Windows". Then when I choose said "Windows" it goes to a black screen that kind of looks like DOS then says choose CD type giving options "1" & "2" but no description of either, and no option to choose one.

I have also tried holding the "C" button on boot with the disk in the drive for Ubuntu/Mate & I end up on the same screen.

Does anyone know how to install Ubuntu or Ubuntu Mate on an older imac? Would be greatly appreciated if you would help me make this happen.

Also It needs a 32Bit version of Linux if possible as it will not support more then 4GB of DDR2 667. The hard drive is 1TB though so space isn't an issue. I prefer Ubuntu Mate if at all possible.

Answer (score 0):

Well I am not sure why I did not think of this before but I had forgotten that all of my disks & USB drives are 64Bit versions. I just downloaded Ubuntu Mate 32Bit & it boots fine.

I'm luvin it!